# Not able to read contact's all values

Tags: java, android

I have made an application of reading all contacts and its values from android address book, but i am not able to read all the vlaues of contact.
Currently i am getting only its name and mobile number.

How can i get its all phone numbers,all eamil values and address values ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am trying to read contacts detail from my application. I have curser object. how can i find out contact's all detail.
I want sync my contacts.

Comment: Uri contacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
      Cursor cur = managedQuery(contacts, projection, null, null, null);   
   if (cur.moveToFirst()) { String name; String phoneNumber;           
            int nameColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME); 
            int phoneColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);       
            do {
                name = cur.getString(nameColumn);
                phoneNumber = cur.getString(phoneColumn);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Also, you are not extracting out the e-mail column, which would explain why you aren't getting that result.

Comment: How can i find out eamil and address columns.I didnt get any thing which returns eamil and address columns, like phoneColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER); for phone column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't put code in the comments. Edit your original post, it makes it much easier to read.

Second, this is a bit of a complicated issue with Android. Contact information is not all in the same place, so if you want it **all** you're going to have to execute multiple queries. Here's an example of getting all the phone numbers cut and pasted from [this thread](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=27867):

```
void trythiscode(){
   // An array specifying which columns to return.
   String[] projection = new String[] {
   People._ID,
   People.NAME,
   People.NUMBER,
};

   // Get the base URI for People table in Contacts content provider.
   // which is: content://contacts/people/
   Uri contactUri = People.CONTENT_URI;

   // Best way to retrieve a query; returns a managed query.
   Cursor peopleCursor = managedQuery (contactUri,
     projection, //Which columns to return.
     null, // WHERE clause--we won't specify.
     null, // Selection Args??
     People.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER); // Order-by name

   // go to the beginning of the list
   peopleCursor.moveToFirst();


   // So, here we have a contact. We need to get the contact ID (_id) then
   // build the Uri to get the phones section of that user's record
   // which is a subdirectory of a contact record

   long personId = peopleCursor.getLong(peopleCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

   Uri personUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contactUri, personId );

   // So now the URL looks like: content://contacts/people/_id(where the actual id of the record is here)
   Uri phoneUri=
    Uri.withAppendedPath(personUri, Contacts.People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

   // Now the URL looks like: content://contacts/people/_id/phones (where phones is literally "phones")

   // Now get all the phone numbers for this contact
   Cursor phonesCursor = managedQuery(phoneUri,
     null,
     null,
     null,
     Phones.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

   // We now have a cursor for all the phone numbers for that User ID
   // go to the beginning of the phone list.
   phonesCursor.moveToFirst();


}
```

And it's entirely possible that this is outdated(I haven't tried it). You'll have to spend some time reading the documentation in case they updated things in Doughnut.